# Python not automatically using non-numeric columns where it should

Tags: python, pandas, type-conversion

I'm taking an AI and ML course using Python.  Somewhere along the line, my implementation stopped automatically adjusting for non-numeric columns where it used to and where it does for others.

Some examples:

1. Running a correlation matrix:

```
# Select only numerical columns - Workaround
numerical_df = df.select_dtypes(include='number')

plt.figure(figsize=(15, 7))
sns.heatmap(numerical_df.corr(), annot=True, vmin=-1, vmax=1, fmt=".2f", cmap="Spectral")
plt.show()

# Original
#plt.figure(figsize=(15, 7))
#sns.heatmap(df.corr(), annot=True, vmin=-1, vmax=1, fmt=".2f", cmap="Spectral")
#plt.show()
```

The original works for most people, but gives me: ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'A'
Using the Select only numerical columns works and gives the same result that most get without the extra step.  Since this is relatively easy to work around it's one of the less critical situations.

2. KMeans Clustering:  Since the labels are non-numeric, not sure the workaround here.

```
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=2, random_state=0, n_init=10)
kmeans.fit(subset_df)

# adding kmeans cluster labels to the original dataframe
df["K_means_segments"] = kmeans.labels_

cluster_profile = df.groupby("K_means_segments").mean()
```

TypeError: Could not convert GMOPQUVWXY to numeric

This code works fine for the instructor and my classmates.  Any ideas what the problem could be with my IDE and how to fix it?

Edit:  Example 2 I was also able to workaround by first creating a dataframe with just the numeric columns, but I shouldn't need to do that.

Comment: For accuracy's sake, this is a "pandas" question, not a "Python" question.  When importing data, `pandas` looks at the data within each column to decide what type it is.  If there is any non-numeric data, the column becomes a different type.  pandas only works in columns -- the whole column is a single type, and the type doesn't change.  Are you importing from a CSV?  Without seeing your data, there is little we can do.

Comment: If you say that it was working before and not now, maybe it is because you have upgraded/downgraded the pandas version you were working with. Also, confirm if you are using the same version as your instructor.

Comment: I reinstalled everything in my Python implementation including pandas.  I'm using pip but it's the latest version available from pip and I checked the update as well.  Instructors and other classmates use a mix of pip and condas and I will check if using condas makes a difference.

Comment: My course mentor was able to solve this for me in a live session.  Putting the answer here in case anyone else having similar trouble.

Comment: With v2.0, Pandas changed a large number of functions including corr() and mean() from having numeric_only default to True to having it default to False.  So, code that worked relying on the pre-2.0 default is now broken in 2.0+ and needs to have the parameter manually set to True to run correctly.